# Liferay7 : Delete title from FORM

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-7

*Hello ,*

I am working with **Liferay 7** and I have no idea how to delete the **Title** and description from **Liferay FORM application**.

*Thank you*

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave them blank, the'y won't appear in UI. Or if you are asking about portlet title, go to look and feel and choose `Application Decorators' as`Barebone`.

Answer (score 0):

Try those 3 steps :

1- Go to the Look and feel configuration

2- Use Custom Title switch it to : YES

3- Try to make the title empty for all languages

4- Save and refresh you page